# NSView added as subview doesn't show

Tags: macos, cocoa, nib, viewcontroller, nssplitview

I have a puzzling problem. Working on a cocoa app in mac os x 10.7.

My app main window contains a split view. In a certain use context in one of the subviews of the split view is loaded a custom view with some labels (nstextfield) and a split view (instantiating a view controller that loads a nib and getting view from that controller). Frame of the custom view is set to split view subview bounds and everything works fine.
Problem is that one of the subviews of the second split view should be loaded (same method: view controller-nib-view-frame/bounds) with a custom view containing a table view and a button, but in this case nothing shows. Everything is done the same way but last custom view is not visible. Any idea?

Thanks

(edit)

this is the code I use to instantiate controller for the view to be added, get the view, and add it as subview to a subview of the split view

```
- (void)loadSubview {

    self.subviewToAddController = [[viewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    //nib name is coded in the controller class definition

    [[self.subviewToAddController view] setFrame:[self.splitViewContainerSubView bounds]];
    //container subView is an outlet

    [self.splitViewContainerSubView addSubview:[self.subviewToAddController view]];

}
```

However I don't think the problem is in this code because if I ask the container subview for its own subviews I can see the new subview is present in the list. It just doesn't show. If I add it as a subview of the split view (a test a just made) or as subview of the subview of the most external split view it is correctly showed too (sorry for the confused explanation, I would need a diagram but in this moment I can't make it)

To elaborate more my doubt (I didn't want to misled so I didn't mention before) can't it be a problem of coordinates, so view is correctly loaded and added as subview but is not visible because hidden by something or showed out of visible area?

(update)

Sorry it took so long to post an update.
After more testing I found out the problem is related to autolayout. No idea what the exact problem is and how to solve it. I ended up turning it off for the nibs the were in troubles and use the old way to set interface objects position and size/resize. Not the best way but for now I can go on.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code that adds the custom view as a subview of the desired parent view.

Comment: Unless you've done some bounds manipulations to the parent view, its bounds should be the correct rectangle for the child view's `frame` for the child view to occupy the entirety of its parent. You can check using `NSLog`.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that you didn't set the autoresizing masks of the view properly.